# PermissionsAndroid request causes RN app to crash (0.71.8)

Tags: android, react-native

I have a react native app (0.71.8) for android to send SMS messages. On app startup, I check the permissions. If they are not set, I request them with the code below.

The checking of the permissions work, but requesting them causes the app to crash. The dialog still shows up and I get grant the permission, and when I startup the app again I see that the permission is given, but I just don't want my app to crash every time the permissions dialog shows up.

Is this a known bug in PermissionsAndroid? I was using react-native-permissions first but the same thing happened (they are using PermissionsAndroid as well).

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native';

  const checkPermission = () => {
    PermissionsAndroid.check(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.SEND_SMS).then(
      status => {
        if ((status === PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.GRANTED)) {
          setHasPermission(true);
        } else {
          requestPermission();
        }
      },
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkPermission();
  }, []);

  const requestPermission = () => {
    PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.SEND_SMS).then(
      status => {
        if ((status === PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.GRANTED)) {
          setHasPermission(true);
        } else {
          setHasPermission(false);
        }
      },
    );
  };
```

Comment: Facing same issue (react-native": "0.68.6").

Comment: I'm getting the same problem. any luck?